# Exchange 2007 Not Allowing Mail To Be Sent From Console App

Tags: c#, email, console, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to send email using Exchange 2007 from a console app using the following code and I get this error message in the exception that gets thrown on the Send call.

> The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.1 Client was not
>   authenticated

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
message.To.Add("to@domain.com");
message.Subject = "test";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationUtil.SMTPServer);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@example.com", "password");
smtp.Send(message);
```

This worked on Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an Exchange 2007 issue and had nothing to do with code.

Comment: So what was the actual issue?

Comment: I needed a mail route opened on the Exchange server from the machine I was using so Exchange would accept mail sent from it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like you need to connect to Exchange via SSL.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationUtil.SMTPServer, 465);
```

Substitute that port number for the port that your Exchange server's secure connection is listening on.